# Access 2013 Group By Date

Tags: ms-access

I have the following problem. 
I have a report where i group my records by date.
The problem is that even though it's grouped by date, when there are days with several different customers, it's not grouping them.

It displays this:

Monday - Customer1 - 1500$

Monday - Customer2 - 800$

Monday - Customer3 - 1200$

What i would need is that Access groups all of them together but i can't find a way to fix it.

Here is how i did it.

I created the report and grouped it with weeks with group&sort by
this is the sql that came from Access itself.

```
SELECT Sum(tbTagesAngebote.[Menge/Liter]) AS [SummevonMenge/Liter], tbTagesAngebote.Datum, tbTagesAngebote.[Preis/Liter], tbTagesAngebote.Produkt, WeekdayName(Weekday([Datum],"2"),"0") AS Wochentage, tbTagesAngebote.Kunde
FROM tbTagesAngebote
GROUP BY tbTagesAngebote.Datum, tbTagesAngebote.[Preis/Liter], tbTagesAngebote.Produkt, WeekdayName(Weekday([Datum],"2"),"0"), tbTagesAngebote.Kunde
HAVING (((tbTagesAngebote.Produkt)=3));
```

When i run this query without customers it's displaying it the way i want within the tableview. But when i open the Report itself it want's me to enter a customer parameter.

Does anyone know a way to fix that?

Comment: You have `tbTagesAngebote.Kunde` in the GROUP BY clause, so of course it will show them separately. I don't understand what you wrote below the SQL (and what exactly you are asking).

Comment: The query i posted displays the records seperated.
When i remove everything that has to do with customer within the query, im getting it displayed how i want it but only in the tableview of access.
When i open a report with this query, it want's me to enter a customer parameter ... i dont know why

Comment: Then you still have a group by Customers in "Grouping and Sorting" in report design.

Comment: I already checked that. It's grouped by date/weeks with sum of Menge/Liter and nothing else

Comment: Then please post the actual query that your report uses. The full SQL.

Comment: `SELECT Sum(tbTagesAngebote.[Menge/Liter]) AS [SummevonMenge/Liter], tbTagesAngebote.Datum, tbTagesAngebote.[Preis/Liter], tbTagesAngebote.Produkt, WeekdayName(Weekday([Datum],"2"),"0") AS Wochentage
FROM tbTagesAngebote
GROUP BY tbTagesAngebote.Datum, tbTagesAngebote.[Preis/Liter], tbTagesAngebote.Produkt, WeekdayName(Weekday([Datum],"2"),"0"), 
HAVING (((tbTagesAngebote.Produkt)=3));`

Thats the query i use.
And i group the report by Datum with Group and Sorting

Comment: Check the report properties, tab Data, if there is a sorting or filter with Customer. --- (and there is a `,` in your SQL before HAVING that doesn't belong there)

Comment: Filter is empty, only Recordsource is set which is the sql 
And the `,` happend while i posted the query im not using it with `,`

Comment: Well. Can you share (on a file hoster) a stripped down copy of your database that still shows the issue?